# Making a diamond with specific widht and height in c (gnuplot)

Tags: c, ubuntu, gnuplot

So I am trying to make a program that outputs the coordinates of a diamond of n width and n height and then represent the figure.out that is done with the program with gnuplot. I have this code done already but I want to make it easier.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#define DEF 10
int main() 
{ 
   float def_an,def_al,slope,i,j,height,width; 
   FILE *out = fopen ( "diamond.out", "w" );
   
   if(out==NULL)
   {
       printf("Wrong output");
       return 1;
   }

   printf("Introduce the height: "); 
   scanf("%f", &height); 
   printf("Introduce the width: "); 
   scanf("%f", &width); 
   def_al=(height/DEF);
   def_an=(width/DEF);
   slope=(height/width);


   for(j=0;j<= height/2;j+=def_al) 
   { 
       for(i=((j-(height/2))/slope);i<=(((height/2)-j)/slope);i+=def_an) 
       {   
           printf("%.2f %.2f\n",i,j); 
           fprintf (out, "%.2f %.2f\n", i,j );
       } 
   } 

   for(j=(0-def_al);j>= -height/2;j-=def_al) 
   { 
       for(i=(((-height/2)-j)/slope);i<=((j-(-height/2))/slope);i+=def_an) 
       {   
           printf("%.2f %.2f\n",i,j); 
           fprintf (out, "%.2f %.2f\n", i,j );
       } 
   } 
   
   fclose(out);
   
   return 0; 
}
```

Comment: gnuplot knows how to draw lines between points.  So you can just output 5 points; you don't need loops at all.

Comment: Are you serious? I have been all the night making that code lol. Okay but how can I make it then? I mean can you give me an example of what gnuplot would represent for 5 points?

Comment: well, but the diamond should be filled inside, not opaque

Comment: It's been a while since I used gnuplot.  I would have to find and read its documentation.  You can, too.

Comment: @Tenko I'd recommend to do some research about `plot with polygons` or `set object polygon` in gnuplot; there are plenty of examples in the manual, on SO and in google...

Answer (score 0):

Plotting a bunch of customized diamonds is not as straightforward as you might think.
Of course, you can use the suggestions Eldrad mentioned in the comments, but the plotting style `with polygons` is for `splot` and "3D"-plotting (which probably could also be used for 2D as well).

So, instead of plotting data you could draw objects (check `help polygon`) in a for loop from data in a datablock.
The example below is just gnuplot code. You have to create this text with C or any other language and send it to gnuplot.

**Code:**

```
### plotting diamonds in custom size
reset session

# x,  y, width, height
$Diamonds <<EOD
 0   0   3   5
 5   0   2   1
 4   4   3   2
-7   5   4   4
-6  -6   3   5
 6  -6   7   2
EOD

x(n) = word($Diamonds[n],1)
y(n) = word($Diamonds[n],2)
w(n) = word($Diamonds[n],3)
h(n) = word($Diamonds[n],4)

set size square
set xrange [-10:10]
set yrange [-10:10]

do for [i=1:|$Diamonds|] {
    set object i polygon from x(i),y(i)+h(i)/2. to x(i)+w(i)/2.,y(i) to x(i),y(i)-h(i)/2. to x(i)-w(i)/2.,y(i) to x(i),y(i)+h(i)/2.
    set object i fc lt i fillstyle solid 1.0 border
}

plot NaN notitle    # empty dummy plot or plot something else
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: It seems good but I should be able to do it with plot "diamond.out" pt 5 ps 8

Comment: @Tenko you don't mention `pt 5 ps 8` in your question. I am confused. In gnuplot `pt 5` is a filled square, not a filled diamond (this would be `pt 13`). Do you just want to plot the circumference of diamonds by a line? Or do you want to plot the circumference of a diamond (coordinates stored in `'diamond.out'` by square points `pt 5 ps 8`? Where do you define the center x and y position of the diamond? Please clarify, ideally add a (hand)sketch graph of the desired output.

Comment: @Tenko are you still interested in a solution? If you as OP don't clarify the unclear details then your question should better be deleted. If you found a solution then please share it with the community. You can answer your own question.